# Why doesn't this awk script see the shell variable?

Tags: linux, awk

Please tell me why this program is not working?? help me improve it.

```
for i in $(seq 2 30); do awk '{if ($i < 0.05) print $1,$i}' test.txt > phen_$i.txt; done
```

File test.txt looks like following:

```
name    phen1   phen2
rs549   0.02    0.02
rs699   0.03    0.03
rs701   1   1
rs751   0.449   0.449
rs884   1   1
rs923   0.9775  0.02
rs970   0.9836  0.03
rs1085  0.0001  0.99
rs1220  0.9316  0.9316
```

output file are expected to be two different files namely phen_2.txt and phen_3.txt containing col1 and col2, and col1 and col3 respectively according to if condition.

expected outcome for phen_2.txt:

```
rs549 0.02
rs699 0.03
rs1085 0.0001
```

expected outcome for phen_3.txt:

```
rs549 0.02
rs699 0.03
rs923 0.02
rs970 0.03
```

please help!

Comment: First of all, is that sequence supposed to be 2 to 3 rather than 2 to 30? Additionally, the $i you use inside awk isn't what you think it is, since you haven't wrapped it in double quotes your shell won't do the variable replacement you're probably intending.

Comment: @Thor84no the sequence is 2 to 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ((i = 2; i <= 30; i++)); do awk -v i="$i" '$i < 0.05 {print $1, $i}' test.txt > "phen_$i.txt"; done
```

Use variable passing (`-v`) to get the shell variable into the AWK script.

You don't need `seq`.

**Edit:**

Fixed some overzealous and bad errors on my part.

Here's how you can do the same thing completely within AWK:

```
awk '{for (i = 2; i <= 30; i++) {if ($i < 0.05) {print $1, $i > "phen_" i ".txt"}}}' test.txt
```

This only goes through the input file once, but it cycles through the set of output files for each line of input. The shell version reads the input file repeatedly, but writes to each output file once.

Comment: Btw, in `bash` you can use `for i in {2..30}`.

Comment: @rush: Of course I know that, but you can't put variables in there which you can do with `seq`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson 30 files are created but they are empty!!

Comment: @IsmeetKaur: That's because I made some changes I shouldn't have. I understand better now what you're trying to do. Does test.txt contain 30 columns? Your question only shows 3. You should have made that clear.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson yes my file has 30 cols....question is just to show an example...i should have mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Use `$'$i'` instead of `$`:

```
for i in $(seq 2 30)
do
  awk '{if ($'$i' < 0.05) print $1,$'$i'}' test.txt > phen_$i.txt
done
```

The problem is that your `$i` from the bash cannot get into the `' '`-string. So you need to close the string before `$i` and open it once again just after.